# Access variable in the same class in Swift

Tags: swift, swift5

Currently, I want to write a APIEndpoint class with contains all of my APIs. I have a variable `baseURL` and I want to use it for the remains. But when I tried to write it as below, it comes to error.

```
class APIEndpoint {
    static let shared = APIEndpoint()
    static let baseURL = "https://13.251.102.94:5001/api/"
    static let login = URL(string: baseURL + "auth/customer/login")!
}
```

My function

```
func performLogin () {
        var request = URLRequest(url: APIEndpoint.shared.login)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let json: [String: String] = ["username": self.name, "password": self.password]
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
        Network.shared.session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            print(JSON(data)["data"])
        }.resume()
}
```

Error:

> **Static member 'login' cannot be used on instance of type 'APIEndpoint'**

in line: `var request = URLRequest(url: APIEndpoint.shared.login)`

Comment: `URLRequest(url: APIEndpoint.login)` should work. The issue is that `APIEndpoint.shared` is a specific `APIEndpoint` instance, like you do: let specificOne = APIEndpoint.shared`, it can't use a `static` method then.

Comment: @CôngToànLê Also. for future reference, if you want to reach something through your singleton, you don't need to make the other values inside your singleton static as well. It's enough with having the `shared` static to reach the other values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

login and `baseURL` are static members of class `APIEndpoint`. You're already could use them as `APIEndpoint.login` and `APIEndpoint.baseURL`. In your case you should write

```
var request = URLRequest(url: APIEndpoint.login)
```